# Java storing file values into an array

Tags: java, arrays, file

Currently I am trying to read all the files from .prg file into an array. Currently the code I have only reads the first line of the file. I would like to read each word within the file and store it within an array. I believe the issue is with the way I am splitting the file but I cannot seem to find a solution

Code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
 public class Reader {
    private Scanner reader

    public Reader(String fileName){

              try {
                   reader = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                         e.printStackTrace();
                 }


        }
    public String[] getInput() {

    String [] input = reader.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
    return input;

}

 }
 public class Player {
     private String[] PlayerInformation;
     private String pName;


public Player(String gName) {
    this.pName = gName;

    this.reader = new 
    Reader("C:\\SpaceInvader\\Files\\PlayerInfo.prg");
    this.PlayerInformation= reader.getInput();
}
 public void ArrayPrintTest() {

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.PlayerDetails));

}
public class Game {

  public Game() {

  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
             Player player = new Player("Player1");
             player.ArrayPrintTest();
             }

}
```

File format:

```
Instruction 1
Jane
ForwardBackUpDown
```

Current Output

```
[Instruction, 1]
```

Expected Output

```
[Instruction, 1, Jane, ForwardBackUpDown]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually reading only the first line of your file, because you are running `reader.nextLine()` only one time.

To read the complete file you can use the [`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) method and use Java Streams:

```
List<String> words = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
        .map(String::trim)
        .map(line -> line.split(" "))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want you result to be an array you can use the [`Stream.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) method instead of [`Stream.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
String[] words = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
        .map(String::trim)
        .map(line -> line.split(" "))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

If you want to read the file without the `Files.lines()` method you can use the following:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
}
```

Now you can use `lines.stream()` and continue with one of the first approaches.

At the end one last hint: If you want to split by any whitespace, not just `" "` you can use `line.split("\\s+")`.

Comment: Thanks for your help managed to get it working with the final solution you proposed

Answer (score 0):

This may fix your problem. You are only splitting by spaces but you have some items on newlines. Each operating system has its own new line code. The code below contains all the different newline codes.

```
String [] input = reader.nextLine().trim().split("\\r?\\n|\\r");
```

Comment: this returns the same thing as my current output but it puts it within one element in the array so instead of being like the currentOutput [Instruction, 1] it is [Instruction 1]

Comment: Try changing nextline() to next() 
String [] input = reader.next().trim().split("\\r?\\n|\\r");